# Search bar controller and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a table with search bar controller and `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
            case .Delete:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
            case .Update:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
            default:
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        self.products = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Product]
    }

}
```

I did all like in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift). All works fine. But if i try to delete row when i do search:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

                    let product = (self.searchController.active) ? self.searchResults[indexPath.row]:self.products[indexPath.row]
                    product.setValue(false, forKey: "inCart")
                    do {
                        try self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }

            })
}
```

I received error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

How edit elements when i use search bar controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating the data set fetched by the fetched results controller without updating the table view.

Understand that you must prepare the table view for changes, then reload the table view, making certain your table view data source methods respond to the change in your data set.

You may also need to ensure your table view delegate methods respond to the changes, depending on your implementation.